# Difference between "whereby" and "in which"?

Tags: differences

Are there any differences between them? For example,

> Conversion is the process **whereby** a value of one type is transformed into a value of
>   another type.

Comment: Cooking is a process whereby something is warmed; A pot is a utensil in which food can be cooked

Comment: Still confusing...Can we say "cooking is a process in which something is warmed; a pot is a utensil whereby food can be cooked."?

Comment: They're just different ways of saying effectively the same thing. Personally, I happen to prefer *whereby* in OP's context, but doubtless some people will feel it's a bit dated/formal/stilted. Whatever - it's Primarily Opinion-Based.

Comment: The difference is that they contain different prepositions—it’s the same difference as that between ‘by’ and ‘in’. _Whereby = by which_ and _wherein = in which_.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

*Whereby* is another way of saying *by which*.  It denotes the **means by which** something occurs.

*In which*, however, denotes the **place or process in which** something occurs.

Thus,

'Conversion is the process **whereby** a value of one type is transformed into a value of another type.'

means that the process is the means by which the value is transformed; however,

'Conversion is the process **in which** a value of one type is transformed into a value of another type.'

means that somewhere in the process one type comes to be transformed, but the process is not necessarily the cause thereof.

The difference is subtle and most people will likely not notice it, but there it is.

Comment: I see. So the essential difference lies in the difference between "by" and "in". Can I say that "whereby" and "by which" are completely the same? If yes, then I think I understood now.

Comment: Yes; *whereby* and *by which* are semantically identical.  It comes from an Anglo-Saxon convention of saying *herein* instead of *in this*, *thereof* instead of *of that*, and *whereto* instead of *to which*, and so on.  Although most of them are now considered archaic, we maintain a few like *whereby, thereby, therefore, heretofore* and so on.

Comment: @Anonym, So in your example, is the first sentence the correct one and the second sentence the wrong one?

Comment: @Pacerier  Both are correct but mean slightly different things.

Comment: @Anonym, But conversion is the cause of "value of one type is transformed into a value of another" isn't it?

Comment: @Pacerier I intentionally left that for the querent to decide.